# syscall(SYS_gettid) returns -1 and errno set to 22(EINVAL)

Tags: c++, system-calls, errno

We had this piece of C++ code that used to work fine, where the **syscall(SYS_gettid)** would return the current thread id correctly. Recently, I noticed the return value is -1.

I understand syscall returns -1 if the operation failed and and corresponding error is set in errno in errno.h. So i tried the following to find out what may be failing.

```
errno = 0;
long jtid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
int errsv = errno;
stream<< "HERE1::" << jtid << "::" << errsv;
```

This has been returning

```
HERE1::-1::22
```

Since 22 is defined as "**#define   EINVAL      22      /* Invalid argument */**"

Could someone help me understand what might be wrong?

Comment: @txtechhelp `gettid` is linux specific

Comment: @CraigEstey, correct .. but there are various versions of Linux with different implementations of `glibc`/`g++`/etc ... and I can't edit my comment to clarify :/

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your `SYS_gettid` has the right value - depending on processor architecture and even number of bits, it can be different numbers - if you call the wrong number, the kernel will obviously look for values in registers you haven't filled in, and thus error out due to "bad argument".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes. It would help if OP posted kernel version, distro type and version, as well as the relevant .h fragments. The syscalls are normally defined as `__NR_*` and the `SYS_*` versions come from `sys/syscall.h` [which includes the dependent .h files internally] and defines: `#define SYS_gettid __NR_gettid`. The actual syscall numbers are arch dependent and different, but I'm not sure that matters here if the standard header files are installed correctly(?)

Comment: However, it wouldn't be the first time header files are NOT installed correctly, or someone googled the SYS_gettid and #defined it to 42 [or whatever google found].

Comment: Yes, again. That's why I suggested posting the stuff. More of a hint to OP [since he gets a copy of the message]. This, so far, hasn't been acted on. Also, should probably post the `#include` statements being used in the app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I believe it is sys/syscall.h. However I cannot confirm it since it's a very large project and I'm compiling each time using this make file we have. I'll keep looking to figure that out. Just did a print of the SYS_gettitd value. Saw that it was defined as 224, whereas in systems where it's working fine the value is 186. On doing a search of the values SYSgettid, 186 and 224, i found this file syscall_impl.h, that defines the value based on the architecture.